# vuejs - asynchronous request and multiple .then explanation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, fetch

actually, I couldn't understand the asynchronous concept when it comes to retrieve data from backend server using **fetch** method.

Why the result of this process is considered as eventual ?

sometimes I come accross examples containing multiple `.then()` which complicates things for me more and more, as on the code below

```js
    return fetch(`URL to service`, {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'include',
    }).then(resp => {
      if (!resp || !resp.ok) {
        throw new Error(this.$t('UnknownServerError'));
      } else {
        return resp.json();
      }
    }).then(data => {
      this.test = data || [];
    });
```

could you explain why this all about ?

Comment: Start at the [`then` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) then look for a decent JS Promises tutorial; this will be covered in detail, including alternatives and lower-level explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you use then, you're coupling the steps in a synchronize process. So if you have command.then(command2).then(command3). However, the chain itself is asynchronous so if you had the following:

```
command.then(command2).then(command3)
command4.then(command5).then(command6)
```

There's no guarantee which one will finish execution first. And if there's a long waiting process (waiting on a response, not waiting as it's executing CPU bound task), it can switch to working on commands in the second task.

Comment: as far as i understood the previous **.then()** and the one which comes next don't have anything in common ? so why we use them in string ? could you give me a real example of the use case ? thanks

Comment: @bouggyren The value returned from `then` is the parameter value for the following `then`. They're directly coupled. Your code *is* a real example and usecase.

Comment: @DaveNewton in this case how would the second **then** work if a delay has occurred in the first one as the returned value is a parameter ? :)

Comment: @bouggyren `fetch` returns a `Promise`. When that promised is resolved, the `then` function is called. It's passed the `Promise` value (`resp` in first example, in the second, if no error, the parsed JSON).

Comment: @bouggyren `then` also returns a `Promise` *(see previously-linked docs)*. The first `then` function *(when no error)* calls `resp.json()`. If we look at [the docs for `json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) we see that `json()` returns a promise. So the first then returns a `Promise`, which is what `then` is supposed to return. When that `Promise` resolves (almost immediately in this case) the second `then` function is called, with the value of the resolved `Promise` as the parameter.